# How to split string by given sub string?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string as follows

```
string fullText ="hello";
string givenCharacters ="hel";
```

after splitting

```
result=["hel","lo"];
```

I want to break it to a two parts from a given characters.

for example i want to break above word using "hel"

how can I do that? appreciate any help

Edit:
another example

```
string fullText ="someText";
    string givenCharacters ="som";

after splitting 

    result=["som","eText"];
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the end result you are seeking...

Comment: can you some more examples?

Comment: I added another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach

```js
var fullText ="hello";
var givenCharacters ="hel";
var output = fullText.split( givenCharacters ).map( function(item, index, arr){ 
    if ( index == arr.length - 1 ) 
    { 
      return item; 
    } 
    else
    { 
      return item + givenCharacters  
    } 
});
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

Split with a regex:

```
> "hello helltown".split(/(hel)/g)
> ["", "hel", "lo ", "hel", "ltown"]
```

Comment: I only want to break it from the beginning. that means result should contain only two items

Comment: This does not split on given characters, but on a string constant, if you decide to split on "llo" you have to revise the regex.

Comment: Thats what `new RegExp()` is for

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with 1 string and 1 split, you can do this:

```
result = [givenCharacters, fullText.split(givenCharacters)];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for the PHP Program:**

```
$fullText ="hello";
$givenCharacters ="hel";
$length = strlen($givenCharacters);
$output = str_split($fullText, $length);
```

Check output:

```
print_r($output);
```

Output will be :

```
Array ( [0] => hel [1] => lo )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getRes(needle , haystack){
    var nPos = haystack.search(needle);
    var sizeofNeedle = needle.length;

  return [haystack.substr(0 , nPos + sizeofNeedle) , haystack.substr(nPos + sizeofNeedle)];

}
  
var myResult = getRes("som" , "someText");

console.log(myResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Var fullText ="hello";
var parts= fullText.split('hel');
for (var i= parts.length; i-->1;)
    parts.splice(i, 0, 'hel');
alert(parts);
```

The reversed loop is necessary to avoid adding hel's to parts of the list that have already had hel's inserted.

Answer (score 0):

JS vanillia developper usualy play like this :

```
var fullText ="hello";
var givenCharacters ="hel";
var result = fullText.split(givenCharacters);
if (fullText.indexOf(givenCharacters) === 0) result.shift();
else result.pop();
result.push(givenCharacters);
result.reverse();
console.log (result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var fullText ="hello";
var g ="hel";

fullText=fullText.replace(g,g+',').split(',');

console.log(fullText); // ['hel', 'lo']
```